# Web service for UTC time to prevent mobile game cheating

Tags: web-services, mobile, cocos2d-x, utc, anti-cheat

I want to prevent "time cheating" via setting the mobile device's clock forward. It's ok for the game to require a network connection. After looking over the numerous "time web service" related resources I'm a bit lost. I just want to submit a request to something like `www.gettime.com/utc` and parse the result to use in my game.

What's a good web service to use for this purpose?

Note the game only requests utc time once on start-up. It looks like I should use an NTP server but I'm not sure which is a good choice. Since the url will be hard-coded in the app it's important to make a good choice.

Comment: What do you plan on doing when the UTC server happens to be down, or blocked by a firewall? There have been other questions regarding the time cheat and if I remember correctly there are reasonable "offline" solutions, too.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The app will attempt to get UTC and if it fails (and has a network connection) then just proceed "normally" i.e. not worry about time cheats. If there's no network connection then the app tells user to connect to a network.

Comment: On iOS that behavior may get your app rejected. Specifically: requiring an internet connection that gives the user no benefits while not having any kind of offline mode. If you do provide other online benefits, you'll almost certainly will run your own webserver from which you can get the time.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Other fairly well-known iOS games require network connections. For example Bubble Mania and Clash of Clans. What do you think about just parsing the time from a request to some major website?

Comment: I think it's fair to assume that these games either just don't work without a server (ie they are online games) or provide meaningful service to the user when connected, such as teaming up with other players. From what I've heard you can't have an iOS app that requires internet connection if it isn't obvious to the user why it requires internet, and if online mode provides no benefit to the user (ie the game could as well be played offline).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have here a 'web service' that offers you the [current UTC time in millis](http://currentmillis.com/api/millis-since-unix-epoch.php). A simple GET request will suffice... If you go to the homepage you will see a similar link that gives you the seconds since the epoch.